# Cannot find the AddObject method in EF6 for inserting records

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

I have not used the entity framework for a while and now I have to do it again with EF6. For queries, everything seems to be working just like in the past. I define a context as

```
var ctx = new DBContext();
```

and, from then on ctx. and IntelliSense will show me the available methods, tables and such. However, for insertion, I used to type

```
ctx.AddToMyTable();
```

but it seems to be deprecated. I read that you're supposed to use `ctx.MyTable.AddObject()`, but I don't have it either. I can only find `Add` and `AddRange`. Did I do something wrong with the mapping? Is there anything I'm missing? Just for your info, I am using EF6 and my database is MySql and I already had plenty of trouble for mapping the database model (buy I made it). Another piece of information that may be important for your analysis: I'm developing with Visual Studio Community 2013.

Can someone please tell me how I can insert the records?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Add` or `AddRange` will work.

`Add` will attach one object, `AddRange` will attach multiple objects in one go.

[More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx)

Comment: Just marked it as correct answer. Thanks very much. It's explained very clearly in the link you sent me.